# My android app stopped when i add icon to listview

Tags: android, listview, crash, imageview, rendering

I want to add an icon to listview. I wrote this and the app now crashes:

```
 ImageView limage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.simge);
 limage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_home);
```

The log-cat error shown in Android monitor is:

> 07-15 15:30:00.056 22943-22943/com.tako.dopingeng E/dalvikvm: Could
>   not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced
>   from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering

Comment: please clean your project and build again.

Comment: share full logcat

Comment: @Omi   https://paste.ubuntu.com/25096320/

Comment: @JaydeepPatel i did but did not work

Answer (score 0):

set background in xml rather then runtime using ,

```
android:src="@drawable/icon_home"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it very simple then use

setImageDrawable(getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable. icon_home));